# C++ Upload large files over HTTP request, without reading whole file into the http request

Tags: c#, c++, qt, http, upload

My program needs to upload huge files of 1GB,2GB,etc . I have tried using QHttpMultipart request & other PUT & POST requests on QNetworkAccessManager. Every time a QNetworkRequest is build, the application memory shoots **up from 20MB to 1GB or 2GB as per the file**, which leads to my application crashing (WINDOWS QT APP).

```
{

QHttpMultiPart *multiPart = new QHttpMultiPart(QHttpMultiPart::FormDataType);

    QHttpPart textPart;
    textPart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, QVariant("form-data; name=\"text\""));

    textPart.setBody("my text");

    QHttpPart imagePart;
    imagePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader,QVariant("image/jpeg"));
    imagePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, QVariant("form-data; name=\"image\""));

    QFile *file = new QFile("LargeFile.zip");

    file->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

    imagePart.setBodyDevice(file); 

    file->setParent(multiPart); 

    multiPart->append(textPart);
    multiPart->append(imagePart);

    QUrl url("http://my.server.tld");
    QNetworkRequest request(url);

    quint64 contentlength = file->bytesAvailable();
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentLengthHeader,contentlength);
    request.setAttribute(QNetworkRequest::DoNotBufferUploadDataAttribute,true);

    QNetworkAccessManager manager;
    QNetworkReply *reply = manager.post(request, multiPart);
    multiPart->setParent(reply); 
}
```

**HUGE increase in application memory equivalent to the huge file size at this point after POST request is fired,as whole file is read & added into request body**

What I found in C# is that, it's possible to upload huge files without increasing or reading the whole file. They keep on writing on the http request stream in chunks.

In this code whatever may the File size be in GBs, application memory **never** goes beyond 40MB.

public void upload(string url, string imagename, string imagepath, string finalType)

```
{

    try
    {
        FileStream fileStream = null;
        Stream rs = null;
        WebResponse lobjResponse = null;
        string lstrResponse = string.Empty;
        bool lblnIsConnected = true;
        long mlngBytesUploaded = 0;
        long llngContentLength = 0;
        long[] llngarrProgressStatusData = new long[2];
        string pstrResponse = string.Empty;

        long lintContentLenght = 0;
        string boundary = "---------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
        byte[] boundarybytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n");

        string formdataTemplate = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"\r\n\r\n{1}";
        string formitem = string.Format(formdataTemplate, "abc", "abc-val");
        byte[] formitembytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(formitem);

        string headerTemplate = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"; filename=\"{1}\"\r\nContent-Type: {2}\r\n\r\n";
        string header = string.Format(headerTemplate, imagename, imagename, finalType);
        byte[] headerbytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header);

        byte[] trailer = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n");

        fileStream = new FileStream(imagepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

        lintContentLenght += boundarybytes.Length;
        lintContentLenght += formitembytes.Length;
        lintContentLenght += boundarybytes.Length;
        lintContentLenght += headerbytes.Length;
        lintContentLenght += fileStream.Length;
        lintContentLenght += trailer.Length;

        wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        wr.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
        wr.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
        wr.ContentLength = lintContentLenght;
        wr.Method = "POST";
        wr.KeepAlive = true;

          using (rs = wr.GetRequestStream())
          {
              rs.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);
              rs.Write(formitembytes, 0, formitembytes.Length);
              rs.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);
              rs.Write(headerbytes, 0, headerbytes.Length);

              int bytesRead = 0;
              byte[] bufferSize = new byte[4096];

              llngContentLength = wr.ContentLength;
              llngarrProgressStatusData[0] = llngContentLength;

                          // BECAUSE OF READING FILE DATA in chunks & WRITING IT to the STREAM. HERE WHOLE FILE ISN'T READ & SET INTO REQUEST like in QHTTPMULTIPART request. Application memory remains constant in C# code.** 
              while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(bufferSize, 0, bufferSize.Length)) != 0) 
              {

                  if (!lblnIsConnected) break;
                    mlngBytesUploaded += bytesRead;
                  rs.Write(bufferSize, 0, bytesRead);

                  if (mlngBytesUploaded > llngContentLength)
                      mlngBytesUploaded = llngContentLength;

                  llngarrProgressStatusData[1] = mlngBytesUploaded;
                  NotifyHTTPProgressBarUpdate(mlngBytesUploaded, llngContentLength);
              }

              fileStream.Close();

              if (lblnIsConnected)
              {
                  rs.Write(trailer, 0, trailer.Length);
                  rs.Close();
              }
          }
    }
}
```

Sending file chunks is an option but currently I don't have that support on  my server.

Can you please advice me on similar implementation of above C# code in QT to upload file in a stream over HTTP PUT/POST on a given URL. Is there a way to do the same in c++?

Comment: I can't understand how the memory usage increases on `setBodyDevice()`. Maybe it's on `manager.post`. What Qt version are you using?

Comment: QT 5.4.1. Yes, after post it increases.

Comment: Please add code with `QNetworkRequest::DoNotBufferUploadDataAttribute` to the question (so people won't suggest it again).